# How to fetch parameters appended in a url, from an adrress bar of a webbrowser using a python code

Tags: python, url, oauth-2.0, odoo

While using OAuth 2.0, after allowing my web application to access the Directory API with Google Sign in, the Google redirects me back to my web application page with an authorization code appended at the URL.

like this->>>
    http://www.mydomain:8069/?code=4%2FZ6tHz_FoteiCGYMfbADu3_1.AjMpYP1TpHAVXE-sT2ZLcbTj9a4FiwI&db=training_crm#menu_id=108&action=101

Now I need to fetch this code from the URL, in order to exchange for a Acess token. How can I grab this code parameter in the URL,with a python code??

(**Working on OpenERP)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are after is a way to grab data from the **query string**.
How you access this depends on the way your webserver interfaces with your python modules. It will usually be stored in some environment variables that the webserver passes to your application as part of a HTTP request from a client.

Looking at https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/server/routing/ it seems like OpenERP provides you with some helper classes for url routing and a request wrapper.

I would suggest using the openerp.http.HttpRequest.

---

**EDIT**: [Reading over this document](https://doc.openerp.com/trunk/web/web_controllers/), it would seem that OpenERP provides you with what they call a 'controller' base class whose methods can be used for url routing. (that is, for deciding what content to present the client with depending on the url)

If you folder structure is as such:

```
web_example
├── controllers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_controllers.py
├── __init__.py
└── __openerp__.py
```

Then you can define these methods in the my_controllers.py file. This is an example of the my_controller.py module (from the aforementioned documentation):

```
class MyController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/my_url/some_html', type="http")
    def some_html(self):
        return "<h1>This is a test</h1>"

    @http.route('/my_url/some_json', type="json")
    def some_json(self):
        return {"sample_dictionary": "This is a sample JSON dictionary"}
```

This class inherits from the OpenERP.http.Controller class, which provides all the base methods and attributes for your 'controller'. Each method has a decorater ('@http.route') which tells the base class that this method is for url routing.

This is from the documentation:

> Each time you define a method with @http.route() it defines a url to
>   match. As example, the some_html() method will be called a client
>   query the /my_url/some_html url.

So in this example, your web app would route www.mysite.com/my_url/some_html to a page that says 'this is a test' in a html heading tag.

But you wanted to capture the query string (the variables after the '?' in the url). According to this same documentation, this can also be done with the controller class. In the url you provided in your question, the query string is composed of the variables 'code' and 'db', as well as their corresponding variables. This method of transferring data between two machines using HTTP is called the GET method.

For your server to do something with these variables you can use the controller class again. In each of your @http_route methods you can get HTTP parameters as named arguments of the method. For example:

```
class MyController(http.Controller):

    @http.route('/', type="http")
    def some_html(self, code, db):
        return "the code is {0}, the db is {1}".format(code,db)
```

Then this method would catch parameters of the url you gave in your question, and be able to do something with it.

Hope this was useful.